# Can I turn my version of Linux into a bootable drive?

Tags: kali-linux

I recently started on Kali for penetration testing and I've written some scripts of my own, built and added on some programs along with creating a virus of my own. I know want to convert this into a bootable drive which I can use to run a live version of my os on there devices. I want it to include the stuff I have added onto it. Sort of like if I can create a copy of my current computer (Softwares, OS, and data) and turn it into a bootable drive so that I can access it anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kali have built-in support to do exactly that, with `persistence`.

Check [this](https://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence) out.

---

You just need to create another partition on your, for example, USBdrive,
and mark that partition as a `persistence` one. See the article to see how.Then, when you boot the system in `persistence mode`, that partition will be mounted in [`overlay mode`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Overlay_filesystem), and all the files you add or replace to the original image, will be there.

---

On the other hand, if you really want to modify your Kali image, so, you don't have to use `persistence`, and generate a modified ISO version of the system with your mods, you can do that too, but is much more painful: you'll need, for example, `xorriso`, `unsquashfs`, and it'll be a lot more work. Unless you really NEED to modify the original ISO, go for the `persistence` option. You can even use `persistence` with encryption, and works perfectly well.

---

Although I think a new clean and live system with your mods added on a `persistence` partition is your best bet, if you want EXACTLY what you have right now (I think that this is not a good idea, cause that system probably wasn't thought to do this from the very beginning, and you may end up with undesired effects) you can try to clone you whole system into a USBDrive. What `whole system` means, depends on your particular installation: could be just one partition on one drive, and the space before it (MBR, and alike); could be multiple partitions, with `ESP` partition included if you are using `GTP` and `UEFI boot` in one drive, or could be even multiples partitions across multiple drives... Depends entirely on how you installed your system. For cloning, you can use tools like `dd`, `pv`, or, even [`clonezilla`](https://clonezilla.org/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This opens up so many options. I'll see which helps me the most and try that.